# Summation of multiples

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, sum

I am learning python and can't get my head around this program.
I just can't seem to find the right loop to get the result.

Q:Create a Python function named sum Of Multiples that has two integer parameters x and n.

Example:sum Of Multiples(3,5);

Expected output:46

Comment: No code shown. Sounds like a beginner task. [mre]? What is your exact problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is simple math, the sum is equivalent to `1 + x*(1+2+3+...+n)`, so `1 + x*(n*(n+1)//2)`:

```
def sumOfMultiples(x,n):
    print(1+x*n*(n+1)//2)
    
sumOfMultiples(3, 5)
46
```

Answer (score 1):

The question basically is asking you to sum all n mutliples of x. So just do this,

```
def sumOfMultiples(x, n):
  m_sum = 1
  for i in range(1, n+1):
    m_sum += i*x
  return m_sum

sumOfMultiples(3,5)
```

You can also do this,

```
sumOfMultiples = lambda x,n: sum([1] + [x*i for i in range(1, n+1)])
sumOfMultiples(3,5)
```

Comment: don't use `sum` as a variable name, this is a python builtin ;)

Comment: @mozway That was a quick comment!!!! And damn you beat me again! And thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 1):

```
sum = 1 + x + 2x + 3x + ... +
```

could be written as sum = `1+x(0+1+2+3+...)`

so just use a for loop from 0 to n or n+1 depending on where you're supposed to stop and multiply the result with x. Or even shorter use sum and range:

```
def sumOfMultiples(x, n):
    print(1+sum(range(n+1))*x)
```

Comment: You forgot the + 1

Comment: Also realized and fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let's just say this should get the job done, but not really optimized:

```
def sumOfMultiples(x,n): 
    x_muti = [1]
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        x_muti.append(x*i)
    print(sum(x_muti))
    
sumOfMultiples(3,5)
```